# After logging in with facebook returning to index page results in DBALException

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I'm attempting to integrate `FOSUserBundle`, `SonataUserBundle` and the `HWIOauth` bundle, I've configured the `SonataUserBundle` to *extend* the `FOSUserBundle`.

Using [this guide](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697) as a basis, i've managed to setup the OAuth integration: a user is successfully created after authenticating with, in this case, a facebook account.

After the authentication, the user is automatically redirected to my index page, which throws a DBALException right after

```
DEBUG - Read SecurityContext from the session 
DEBUG - Reloading user from user provider.
```

because of an invalid table reference in the `WHERE` clause:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.username AS username2, [more t1 references] FROM fos_user t1 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1' with params {"1":1}:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'
```

I understand that the `t0` reference is invalid because it's not included in the `FROM` clause, but have **no idea** why it's referring to `t0.id` instead of `t1.id`

---

(hopefully) Relevant Code
If I understand correctly, my User entity extends the `Sonata` User entity, which in turn extends the `FOS` User entity ?

**Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of the <name> project.
 *
 * (c) <yourname> <youremail>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the Sonata EasyExtends bundle ( http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends )
 *
 * References :
 *   working with object : http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/working-with-objects/en
 *
 * @author <yourname> <youremail>
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**Sites\SiteBundle\Entity\User.php**

```
<?php
namespace Sites\SiteBundle\Entity;

use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    private $facebook_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    private $facebook_access_token;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    private $google_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    private $google_access_token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your code here
    }
```

relevant part of **config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Sites\SiteBundle\Entity\User
sonata_user:
    security_acl: false # was true
    manager_type: orm
    class:
        user:         Sites\SiteBundle\Entity\User
```